# How do you say "ebook" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, from-english, non-native-speaker

Google translate gives me "електронна книга" but I would've guessed there would be a shorter word - is there not? What word do people actually use?

Comment: The closest i can think is "Є-книга" which is basically the same of what e-book to electronic book is

Comment: I am afraid Google is right. We normally say "електронна книга/книжка". You can omit "електронна" if it is clear or there's no need in pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *електрика* and many of its derivatives<sup>(*1)</sup> — including *електроніка* and *електронний* — [are usually shortened](https://abbrs.info/?text=%D0%B5%D0%BB.) to *ел.*, therefore [*ел. пошта*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D0%B5%D0%BB.+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%22), [*ел. книга*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D0%B5%D0%BB.+%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%22) are in usage.

Other variations are usually calques or transcriptions: *е(-)книга*, *і(-)книга*, *е(-)бук*, *і(-)бук*.

For comparison, let's take a look at how the word *e-mail* is translated to Ukrainian according to some dictionaries:

- *Імейл*, I guess, due to [Russian influence](https://technolex.com/ru/new-tips/kak-pravilno-emejl-e-mejl-emejl-imejl-i-mejl-email-e-mail-e-pochta.html) <sup>*ru*</sup> as *Академический орфографический словарь* <sup>*ru*</sup> was accepted by [*Словник української мови у 20 томах*](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=218195&page=1218).
- *Епошта* was accepted by *[Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=e-mail&dicts=2&highlight=on) (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)*.
- *Е-пошта* was accepted by *[Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська 2010](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=e-mail&dicts=4&highlight=on) (О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович)*, *[Українсько-англійський словник з радіоелектроніки 2015 – 2018](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=e-mail&dicts=16&highlight=on) (Богдан Рицар, Леонід Сніцарук, Роман Мисак)* and *[Англійсько-український словник сучасних термінів з ІТ 2001–2011](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=email&dicts=3&highlight=on) (linux.org.ua) <sup>?</sup>*.

---

<sup>(*1)</sup> a notable exception is *електричний* which gets abbreviated as *елек[тр]*:

> *електросушарка* — electric dryer

Comment: So am I right to conclude that there's no single settled answer in common use and if I want to google for "ebook <some title>" I need to try multiple versions of the word?

Comment: @weronika Sadly, but, yeah, thereʼs no single settled answer. For to google you can use one-two variations because Google [usually] knows about synonyms.

Comment: Ти забув варіант просто електронна книжка. Крім того - електронна, не електрична.

Comment: @improbable перечитайте запитання і відповідь. Бо запитання про скоротку до _електронна книга_, а ваше _крім того_ геть не до місця, бо я не писав _електрична книга_, тут _електричний_ згаданий лише як виняток: не _ел._, а _елек[тр.]_.

Comment: Зрозуміло. Тоді додайте пліз те, що під *derivatives* ви маєте на увазі слово *електронний* і додайте варіант перекладу *електронна книга*. Не завадять також посилання на джерела. **Гугл не є джерелом**. Також заберіть згадування про переклад пошти в першому реченні, бо там воно irrelevant, питання про книгу, тому в першому реченні треба перелічити саме варіанти перекладу e-book.

Comment: @improbable Під _derivatives_ маю будь-що, в тому числі *електронний*, але крім, тобто *except*, *електричний*. Основним джерелом є словник, а ланки на ґуґл є **прикладами**, про що вже зазначено як *in usage*. Немає жодної потреби прибирати, бо *ел. пошта* має ту саму структуру скорочення і те скорочене слово, а отже *relevant*. До чого ще хочете причепитися?

Comment: @stegetsj я теж не з першого разу зрозумів, що йдеться про виняток. З вашого дозволу, я зроблю правку допису — а саме, винесу неважливий виняток у зноску. Якщо це не те, що ви мали на увазі, — не заперечуватиму, якщо ви відкотите (rollback) мою правку.

Comment: @improbable Вам також пропоную одразу робити Edit або Suggested Edit, тоді автор допису може одразу розуміти, в чому полягає запропоноване покращення тексту. А коментар до Edit може містити пояснення, який саме недолік таким чином виправляється.

Comment: @stegetsj, я згоден з Вами, що виправлення/доповнення, запропоновані improbable, необов'язкові, а відповідь і так гарна. Проте, я вважаю, що не варто писати «до чого ще хочете причепитися?», а краще (як рекомендує вікіпедія для своїх учасників) припускати добрі наміри. (Коли людина бачить по-іншому й не розуміє тебе, це може дратувати, але це зовсім необов'язково означає, що вона хоче просто причепитися.)